# How to delete a file, ls -al got: "-????????? ? ? ? ? ?"

Tags: delete, wget, rm, filename

I try to download a model file from civitai.com by wget , and got a filename '201259?type=Model'.
wget https://civitai.com/api/download/models/201259?type=Model&format=SafeTensor&size=pruned&fp=fp16

when I try to "ls -al", and got ls: cannot access '201259?type=Model': No such file or directory
, the file  attributes "-????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ?"
How can I delete it?

Comment: I know this isn't what you're asking: to successfully download the file, put quotes around it. This seems to work for me: `wget 'https://civitai.com/api/download/models/201259?type=Model&format=SafeTensor&size=pruned&fp=fp16'`

Comment: Is it better-behaved once wget terminates?

Comment: FYI:  Your `wget` command was to download `https://civitai.com/api/download/models/201259?type=Model` only, as the character `&` has a special purpose in commands & was interpreted as such... which is why you were suggested to put it in quotes (so it won't be interpreted as the bash instruction of `&`)

Comment: I follow Raffa's instructions, the problem results from  that I didn't and probably closed the terminal killing the background job prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ls` to deal with wierd filenames is suboptimal. Read `man 1 stat`, and do:

```
stat -c "%N\n" 201259*
```

or

```
rm -i 201259*
```

or, let file completion handle it:

```
rm -i 202259<kbd>TAB</kbd>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not discussing how to delete/remove the file (*[@waltinator's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1491082/968501) should be sufficient*), but rather what happened and could happen again if you do the same thing you did.

To see what happened, enable command execution tracing (*in the terminal*) with:

```
set -x
```

... then, run your command (*adding `; jobs` to its end to list background jobs in the current shell*) like so:

```
wget https://civitai.com/api/download/models/201259?type=Model&format=SafeTensor&size=pruned&fp=fp16; jobs;
```

... that would result in this output:

```
[1] 10218
[2] 10219
+ wget 'https://civitai.com/api/download/models/201259?type=Model'
[3] 10220
+ fp=fp16
+ format=SafeTensor
+ jobs
[1]   Running                 wget https://civitai.com/api/download/models/201259?type=Model &
[2]-  Running                 format=SafeTensor &
[3]+  Running                 size=pruned &
+ size=pruned
```

... where `wget` is passed the URL `'https://civitai.com/api/download/models/201259?type=Model'` and is run as a background job i.e. `wget https://civitai.com/api/download/models/201259?type=Model &` ... and two variables/parameters `format` and `size` are being set as `format=SafeTensor` and `size=pruned` in the background as well i.e. `format=SafeTensor &` and `size=pruned &` as background jobs run in their own separate sub-shells with separate process IDs, their assignment will only be available within those sub-shells and will no-longer be available/set after those sub-shells terminate and therefore you can't call them in the current parent shell ... you will see also, that a third variable/parameter `fp` is being set as well `fp=fp16` but it's set in the current shell with no `&` and therefore it will be available and you can call it with e.g.:

```
$ echo "$fp"
+ echo fp16
fp16
```

... if you run `jobs` again (*given the `wget` download is still running*), like so:

```
$ jobs
+ jobs
[1]+  Running                 wget https://civitai.com/api/download/models/201259?type=Model &
```

... you would see only one job running in the background (*the other two have terminated/completed immediately*) ... and if you bring that remaining job to the foreground with:

```
fg
```

... then, you should see the above mentioned `wget` command still running and **if you wait for it to finish** (*as I think you didn't and probably closed the terminal killing the background job prematurely*), it should look like this:

```
$ fg
+ fg
wget https://civitai.com/api/download/models/201259?type=Model
--2023-11-01 09:38:57--  https://civitai.com/api/download/models/201259?type=Model
Resolving civitai.com (civitai.com)... 104.18.23.206, 104.18.22.206, 2606:4700::6812:17ce, ...
Connecting to civitai.com (civitai.com)|104.18.23.206|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 307 Temporary Redirect
Location: https://civitai-delivery-worker-prod-2023-10-01.5ac0637cfd0766c97916cefa3764fbdf.r2.cloudflarestorage.com/model/81744/epicphotogasmz.VG6S.safetensors?X-Amz-Expires=86400&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%22epicphotogasm_z.safetensors%22&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=2fea663d76bd24a496545da373d610fc/20231101/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20231101T063857Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=bb14df26d6a222876d9890c0b61ad83ca2577514edf9a337254b2ba6e7980cd1 [following]
--2023-11-01 09:38:58--  https://civitai-delivery-worker-prod-2023-10-01.5ac0637cfd0766c97916cefa3764fbdf.r2.cloudflarestorage.com/model/81744/epicphotogasmz.VG6S.safetensors?X-Amz-Expires=86400&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%22epicphotogasm_z.safetensors%22&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=2fea663d76bd24a496545da373d610fc/20231101/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20231101T063857Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=bb14df26d6a222876d9890c0b61ad83ca2577514edf9a337254b2ba6e7980cd1
Resolving civitai-delivery-worker-prod-2023-10-01.5ac0637cfd0766c97916cefa3764fbdf.r2.cloudflarestorage.com (civitai-delivery-worker-prod-2023-10-01.5ac0637cfd0766c97916cefa3764fbdf.r2.cloudflarestorage.com)... 104.18.8.90, 104.18.9.90, 2606:4700::6812:85a, ...
Connecting to civitai-delivery-worker-prod-2023-10-01.5ac0637cfd0766c97916cefa3764fbdf.r2.cloudflarestorage.com (civitai-delivery-worker-prod-2023-10-01.5ac0637cfd0766c97916cefa3764fbdf.r2.cloudflarestorage.com)|104.18.8.90|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2132625628 (2.0G)
Saving to: ‘201259?type=Model’

201259?type=Model                                100%[==========================================================================================================>]   1.99G  2.81MB/s    in 11m 34s 

2023-11-01 09:50:32 (2.93 MB/s) - ‘201259?type=Model’ saved [2132625628/2132625628]
```

... which shows that `1.99G` is downloaded and saved as `201259?type=Model` in the current working directory and `ls` should list it like so:

```
$ LC_ALL=en_US ls -alh
+ LC_ALL=en_US
+ ls --color=auto -alh
total 2.0G
drwxrwxr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu 4.0K Nov  1 09:38  .
drwxr-x--- 20 ubuntu ubuntu 4.0K Nov  1 09:50  ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu 2.0G Oct 27 20:29 '201259?type=Model'
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu 119K Nov  1 09:41  wget-log
```

**Notice** each `&` in the URL is interpreted by the shell as a [job control](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control.html) operator that means to send the previous command (*string on its left side*) to execute in the background ... to prevent that behavior, single quote the URL like so:

```
wget 'https://civitai.com/api/download/models/201259?type=Model&format=SafeTensor&size=pruned&fp=fp16'
```

Comment: You are right, I  didn't and probably closed the terminal killing the background job prematurely.